# Is there any synonym for 'be to'?

Tags: word-meaning

I know I could switch *be of* into *have* in many cases as likely as not. Such as...

> This year's cabbages **are of** fine quality.
>
> This year's cabbages **have** fine quality.

But still I can't figure out what synonym would fit for *be to*.

> The President **is to** visit the wall.
>
> You'**re to** be back as soon as possible.
>
> If we **are to** catch him, we have to leave now.
>
> No one **is to** be seen in the street.
>
> He **was to** be like that from birth.

Any help please? From what I guess roughly, are they some formal kind of *be going to*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions using some form of the verb 'be' followed by 'to' are usually used when discussing planned, expected, required, or destined future situations, events or actions.

> The President is to visit the wall.

It has been arranged that the President will visit the wall. It is not certain that he or she will do so; plans can change. The school is opening on Monday, and the mayor is to be at the ceremony.

> You're to be back as soon as possible.

The speaker is saying to the listener, "I instruct you to be back as soon as possible". The messenger knocked on the door and said to me, "I am to give you this note".

> If we are to catch him, we have to leave now.

Here we indicate a necessity imposed by a goal. If we want to catch him, we must leave now. If I am to catch the train, I must go to the station at once. If you are to pass the examination, you must study hard.

> No one is to be seen in the street.

To be seen, to be heard, to be felt, etc discuss the availability of something to the senses or otherwise. The speaker cannot see any people in the street. No sounds are to be heard in the forest. No milk was to be had in the shops. No pulse was to be felt in the old man's neck. Many birds are to be seen in the sky.

> He was to be like that from birth.

This is an odd sentence, since 'he' did not come into existence until his birth. Where did you find it? What might "like that" mean? He was obese in the womb, and in fact, he was like that from birth? The ten-year-old Barack Obama played with his friends; he was to be President 38 years later. "Was to be" indicates that something not known at some past time would be the case later.